# ASP.NET Website display wrong data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I built a web application using `ASP.NET`, data stored at `SQL Server 2008`.

The application is running ok, **but once a couple of day the application displays wrong data and i get error when i enter some pages**. system return to normal work after 5 minutes by it self.

can someone give a clue what is the problem?

I'm getting error on lines which try to take data from retrieved DataTable:
like:

```
txtbx_contact_fullname.Text = dt_contact.Rows[0]["Contact_Fullname"].ToString();
```

or

```
lbl_Creation_datetime.Text = dt_YC_Last_Transaction.Rows[0]["Creation_datetime"].ToString();
```

usually these lines works perfect, and there is no reason that the datatable will return empty.
the error i get is:
Column 'xxxxx' does not belong to table.

The Query that retrieve the data is:

```
SELECT [Request ID],[Creation Date],[Request Status],[Contact Fullname],[Start Date],[Start Time],[End Date],[End Time],[Work Mode],[Comments],[HPM Points],[FA Points]
FROM  dbo.vw_All_Requests
WHERE [Request Status] = @YellowCard_Status
ORDER BY [Creation Date] DESC
```

From some reason some columns do not get back..

Comment: Could you write the errors because your code can run with some errors

Comment: Its hard to know. We need more info. Otherwise it will all be "guesses in the dark". Guess: Maybe data is cached in a sub optimal fashion?

Comment: Perhaps you could drop your SQL into your post also.

Comment: I take the data from a View

Comment: perhaps you could move to `ASP.NET MVC` and use `EntityFramework` with `LINQ`. Then you'll experience a much better way of building web applications :)

Comment: Contact Fullname and Contact_Fullname are diffent

Comment: don't sure but both have underscore..

Comment: @user454558 check both column name may be "_" is used intsted of white space

Comment: You are not handling the case where you have no row returned by the query, in which case index 0 would be invalid.

Comment: @Tarik if rows not return than exception will be row 0 can't be find not clolumn find:)

Comment: In the abscence of other details and the context in which this code is running, I would still put this check in place, just in case you overlooked something in your view that makes it return zero rows.

Comment: The other thing that came to my mind is how do you create the DataTable? Are you creating it through code or was it generated by the designer? If it was generated by code, maybe you fail to add a column for some reason. Please, post relevent code to help.

Answer (score 0):

`txtbx_contact_fullname.Text = dt_contact.Rows[0]["Contact Fullname"].ToString();
lbl_Creation_datetime.Text = dt_YC_Last_Transaction.Rows[0]["Creation datetime"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

you column name in asp.net code has _ for example full_name but in sql query it does not have _, i don't know you've assigned names to your datatable or not but give attention to this issue ...

Comment: all my columns have words seperated by "_" and it works good, and i have several databases. 
Only in that particular application i have problems that last 5 minutes once a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

if you code is correct. you are calling `Creation_datetime` from .NET code, but in SQL you have **no such column**, what you do have is a `Creation date` **only** (from your `SELECT` query).

so, to fix your problem, all you need to do is change

```
dt_YC_Last_Transaction.Rows[0]["Creation_datetime"]
```

to

```
dt_YC_Last_Transaction.Rows[0]["Creation_date"]
```

**after the issue is fixed**, you should learn a better way to query the database using explicit names, for example, using objects instead calling the string value... You should learn a bit of Entity Framework and Linq, it will improve your code a lot.

Comment: Thanks for advice,
but again, my application works fine for 99% of the time.
so the name of the column is not the issue..

Comment: then your code is not the one you posted, as if it is, it will never work 100% of the time! Your **select query** does not have any `Creation_datetime` column selected and you are requesting that, and worst, you are using `ToString()` so you're not even check for `null` values ...